# Heroku CSV gets wiped after 1 day, all the data is lost.

Tags: php, html, facebook, csv, heroku

I have an application for Facebook , deployed on Heroku . This application collects some user data into a CSV, when someone completes a form. However, i have a problem with this CSV. It gets wiped completely (only the header remains) every day.

I will provide the PHP Code on which i'm manipulating the CSV :

Here is the code in which i'm actually manipulating the CSV, writing data to it :

```
<?php
date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Bucharest');
$error = 0;
if($_GET["name"] == ""){
    $error = 2;
}
else if($_GET["email"] == ""){
    $error = 3;
}
else if(!filter_var($_GET["email"], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)){
    $error = 4;
}
if($error == 0){
$list = array($_GET["name"], $_GET["email"],date("d-m-Y H:i:s",time()));
$fp = fopen('users.csv', 'a');
fputcsv($fp, $list);
fclose($fp);
}
header( 'Location: index.php?signedrequest='.$_GET["signedrequest"].'&errors='.$error );

?>
```

Here is the code for an admin page to download the CSV :

```
<div id="admintab">
<p>
<iframe name="myframe_targ" style="display:none;"></iframe>
Download : <a href="users.csv" target="myframe_targ">users.csv</a>
</p>
</div>
```

I mention that this application is hosted on Heroku and i didn't push any data to it since Monday. My last log indicates that the last push was on Monday at 13:21. However i can see data in CSV only from today. I also check in other days and there were other inputs.

Do you have any idea, why is this happening ? Is there a problem with Heroku or with my PHP code ?

Thanks in advance !!

Comment: Sounds like you should be storing the data in a database instead.

Comment: Storing the data into a database would cost me some money on heroku or atleast to confirm my payment method, which i don't agree to do. What's wrong with writing to a CSV ?

Comment: I believe the data on Heroku is transient.  It's how they scale their network.  Your app is provisioned across potentially dozens or hundreds of machines, which may be re-provisioned or moved around as needed.  You don't *own* a single machine.

Comment: BTW, I run [a site](http://qwk.io) on Heroku and I use [MongoHQ](http://www.mongohq.com/) for storage.  I don't pay anything for either Heroku or MongoHQ, though I can't remember if I had to enter credit card info.

Comment: Thanks for you response ! So you are saying that the last commit will be moved everyday to a new machine and that's why my csv gets wiped everytime ? It makes sense. However, i think one solution would be to host the csv file on a host i own.

Comment: I'm saying you cannot count on transient data being on any machine, ever.  It could be moved around with no notice at any time for any reason.  So yea, definitely check into a better storage solution.

Comment: You can add an answer with one of your comments and I will mark it as correct. Thanks again for the fast answer !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Heroku scales by synchronizing your code across potentially dozens or hundreds of servers within their network.  You cannot depend on transient data stored on an individual instance to be available later on, as the virtual machine handling the request might be different every time.  You can read a bit more on how it works [here](http://www.heroku.com/how).

Ideally, you should be using a storage mechanism built for long-term storage for this task.  I've used [MongoHQ](http://www.mongohq.com/home) a bit, and it works pretty well (They do have a free tier).  A key/value store, such as [Amazon SimpleDB](http://aws.amazon.com/simpledb/) might be a good fit as well.

Answer (score 2):

Whilst you can write to the file system it will be lost on scaling dynos, restarting dynos, redeploying your code. Dynos are cycled on a daily basis by Heroku so this will be the causes of you loss.

Comment: Thanks for your answer ! Someone already explained that to me. It makes sense now. I didn't quite read their documentation carefully.